# try to write linked list

Tags: c#

I am trying to write linked list and have some problems:

This is intNode class:

```
public class IntNode
{
    private int _value;
    private IntNode _next;

    public IntNode(int v, IntNode n)
    {
        _value = v;
        _next = n;

    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public IntNode getNext()
    {
        return _next;
    }

    public void setValue(int v)
    {
        _value = v;
    }

    public void setNext(IntNode n)
    {
        _next = n;
    }
}
```

my linked list class:

```
public class Set
{
    private IntNode _head;
    private IntNode _current;
    private IntNode _lastNode;

    /**
     * create a new empty Set object
     */
    public Set()
    {
        _head = null;
        _current = null;
        _lastNode = null;
    }

    /**
     * check if the object empty
     * @return true if Set object contain elements, false otherwise
     */
    public bool isEmpty()
    {
        return (_head == null);
    }

    /**
     * add number to Set object
     * @param x - the number to be add 
     */
    public void addToSet(int x)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            _head = new IntNode(x, _current);
            _head.setNext(_current);
        }
        else
        {
            _current = new IntNode(x, _lastNode);
            _current.setNext(_lastNode);
        }
    }

    /**
     * return a string representation of this Set 
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String temp = "";

        for (IntNode currentNode = _head; currentNode != null; currentNode.getNext())
        {
            temp += currentNode.getValue() + ",";
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

I have problem with my addToSet and toString methods and i cannot find it.

Comment: "i have problem" tells us nothing.  Please describe the problem you're having - do you get an error or exception?  Does it not behave as expected?

Comment: i don't know if my addToSet method do what it supposed to do and cannot print all the elements inside the object using toString

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    /**
     * add number to Set object
     * @param x - the number to be add 
     */
    public void addToSet(int x)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            _head = new IntNode(x, _current);
            _head.setNext(_current);
        }
        else
        {
            _current = new IntNode(x, _lastNode);
            _current.setNext(_lastNode);
        }
    }
```

To:

```
    /**
     * add number to Set object
     * @param x - the number to be add 
     */
    public void addToSet(int x)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            _head = new IntNode(x, null);
        }
        else
        {
            _current = new IntNode(x, null);
            _lastNode.setNext = _current;
            _lastNode = current;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks ! Object reference not set to an instance of an object in line _lastNode.setNext = _current;

Answer (score 0):

```
for (IntNode currentNode = _head; currentNode != null; currentNode.getNext())
{
   temp += currentNode.getValue() + ",";
}
```

The problem with your for loop in your `toString()` method (on a side-note why not override `ToString()` ? ) is that you are not re-assigning `currentNode`: `currentNode.getNext()` returns a *new* object, that you are not using - instead re-assign it to `currentNode`:

```
for (IntNode currentNode = _head; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.getNext())
{
   temp += currentNode.getValue() + ",";
}
```

This code looks more like Java than C# - look into using properties, observe the naming conventions and use language specific idioms.